# iPhone - call UISwitch that is generated in a UIView when a button is pressed

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uibutton, uiswitch

To clarify my question, my program has three lightbulb on the screen (Customized UIButton)
when any lightbulb is pressed, I programatically generate a UIView with a switch on it
when I turn on the switch, corresponding lightbulb will light up (change its background image)
However, I have trouble accessing this UISwitch since I can't declare it publicly

My code goes something like this:

```
@property buttonA;
@synthesize buttonA;//all three buttons have their background image set to 'off.png'

- (IBAction)lightBulbPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{

  UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1,1, 64, 64)];
  UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,64,64)];
  [mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(onOrOff) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

  [myView addSubview:mySwitch]
  [self.view addSubview:myView];   

}
```

So what troubles me is how to program the selector onOrOff, so that it knows which switch is being touched and change the background image of corresponding button accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about your method:

```
- (IBAction)lightBulbPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    // your method
}
```

You already know who called it. This piece of information is stored in `sender`.
So you can save it and use later in `onOrOff`

By the way, if you are using UISwitch you have to check

```
UIControlEventValueChanged
```

and not UIControlEventTouchUpInside.

EDIT: To pass your `sender` you can store its value to a `NSString *buttonTapped` declared in your .h file

```
- (IBAction)lightBulbPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

if (sender == bttOne) {
    buttonTapped = @"ButtonOneTapped";
} else if (sender == bttTwo) {
    buttonTapped = @"ButtonTwoTapped";
} else if (sender == bttThree) {
    buttonTapped = @"ButtonThreeTapped";
}

  // your method

}

- (void)onOrOff {
    if ([buttonTapped isEqualToString:@"ButtonOneTapped"]) {
        // Button One
    } else if ([buttonTapped isEqualToString:@"ButtonTwoTapped"]) {
        // Button Two
    } else if ([buttonTapped isEqualToString:@"ButtonThreeTapped"]) {
        // Button Three
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the correction,Do u mind show me how to pass sender info to onOrOff method?

Comment: ah i see, so can i also declare a uibutton variable to store the sender itself? because when i have 20 buttons it wud be quite tedius to use 20 if statements

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so, is taht you give them distinct tag numbers in IB, and in `- (IBAction)lightBulbPressed:(UIButton *)sender` method, get their tag. e.g. `NSInteger pressedButtonTag = [sender tag];`, and go from there.

Also, instead of alloc/init `myView` every time user presses a button, you can add that view in IB, add the switch to it, put in the hierarchy of the owner but not the view, and set an outlet to it in .h. Call it whenever you need it, and again, access the switch by tag e.g. ( `UISwitch *mySwitch = (UISwitch *)[myView viewWithTag:kSwitchTag];` ) and do whatever you want to do (on or off), add it to the subview and remove it later. This is more efficient.